# Can't start DroidExplorer because an asset is missing

Tags: droid-explorer

When I open DroidExplorer I get this error:
[image: Error]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: add a png file in that location and try again.

Comment: name your png file '[DEFAULT].png'

Answer (score 0):

you need to create Droidexplorer in ProgramData, and then create assets in DroidExplorer ( all folders )
and then it works
i had the same issue just right now

Answer (score 0):

I found the default.png file here
 ProgramData\DroidExplorer.0.9.0.4.x64.Setup\DroidExplorer.0.9.0.4.x64.exe\2.msi\contents.cab\

Answer (score 0):

As [Eric Dezert's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204933) mentions, create folder C:\ProgramData\DroidExplorer

(note "DroidExplorer" is all one word there, unlike the Program installation folder, which is two words "Droid Explorer" - (same in Windows Registry - multiple entries under 'DroidExplorer' AND 'Droid Explorer'.)

Just copy the entire "Assets" folder from C:\Program Files\Droid Explorer to C:\ProgramData\DroidExplorer (it only contains a few small image files, including the "[DEFAULT].png)